# How can I limit the data in graphics depending on conditions?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formula, bar-chart

I would like to create a bar chart. My data should only include the values in column A, when column D in the same row contains "finished".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter your source data so only `finished` is selected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. The problem is, I need it dynamically. I have to edit data for someone else, so that he can see the desired data whenever he opens the excel sheet. Is that even possible? @pnuts

Comment: Hmm that might be possible. But I have already my data in the column A as a Pivot Chart .... hmm but might work. But then I have to set the filter always before i actualize the pivot chart. It is exactly what I don't want :/ I have rather thought of a formula when editing the data of the bar chart?? Is that possible? @pnuts

Comment: I have tried it with:{=IF(IMs!$D:$D,'finished',IMs!$I$1)} in the row values when editing the desired data. Unfortunately it's not working. @pnuts